# LINQ get x amount of elements from a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a query which I get as:

```
var query = Data.Items
            .Where(x => criteria.IsMatch(x))
            .ToList<Item>();
```

This works fine.

However now I want to break up this list into x number of lists, for example 3. Each list will therefore contain 1/3 the amount of elements from query.

Can it be done using LINQ?

Comment: take a look at (and possible duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq

Comment: MoreLinq has a [`Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) extension method designed to do exactly this. EDIT: Ooops, nevermind. Got it backwards. It defines the _size_ of each list, not the number of lists. Sorry.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Not quite.  `Batch` separates the query into an unknown number of groups, all of size n.  He wants to separate the query into m groups all of an unknown size.

Comment: How do you want to size your groupings if you supply a non-divisible number (like 10 into 3), you would want your groupings to be of lengths `{4, 3, 3}`, `{3, 3, 4}`, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PLINQ partitioners to break the results into separate enumerables.

```
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create<Item>(query);
var partitions = partitioner.GetPartitions(3);
```

You'll need to reference the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. `partitions` will be a list of `IEnumerable<Item>` where each enumerable returns a portion of the query.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this could work, splitting the list into [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx)s.

```
const int numberOfGroups = 3;

var groups = query
    .Select((item, i) => new { item, i })
    .GroupBy(e => e.i % numberOfGroups);
```

Comment: Ah yea, `%` should be used so the group by will be in range `0..(numberOfGroups-1)`

Comment: The problem of `%` approach is that produces sublists of non-consecutive elements: for instance if you have 12 elements you get `{0,3,6,9} - {1,4,7,10} - {2,5,8,11}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Skip` and `Take` in a simple `for` to accomplish what you want

```
   var groupSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(query.Count() / 3d);
   var result = new List<List<Item>>();
   for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      result.Add(query.Skip(j * groupSize).Take(groupSize).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the elements doesn't matter using an `IGrouping` as suggested by Daniel Imms is probably the most elegant way (add `.Select(gr => gr.Select(e => e.item))` to get an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`).

If however you want to preserve the order you need to know the total number of elements. Otherwise you wouldn't know when to start the next group. You can do this with LINQ but it requires two enumerations: one for counting and another for returning the data (as suggested by Esteban Elverdin).

If enumerating the query is expensive you can avoid the second enumeration by turning the query into a list and then use the [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitList<T>(List<T> list, int numberOfRanges)
{
    int sizeOfRanges = list.Count / numberOfRanges;
    int remainder = list.Count % numberOfRanges;

    int startIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRanges; i++)
    {
        int size = sizeOfRanges + (remainder > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        yield return list.GetRange(startIndex, size);

        if (remainder > 0)
        {
            remainder--;
        }

        startIndex += size;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();

    IEnumerable<List<int>> result = SplitList(list, 3);

    foreach (List<int> values in result)
    {
        string s = string.Join(", ", values);
        Console.WriteLine("{{ {0} }}", s);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }
{ 4, 5, 6 }
{ 7, 8, 9 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static IList<List<T>> GetChunks<T>(this IList<T> items, int numOfChunks)
{
    if (items.Count < numOfChunks)
        throw new ArgumentException("The number of elements is lower than the number of chunks");
    int div = items.Count / numOfChunks;
    int rem = items.Count % numOfChunks;

    var listOfLists = new List<T>[numOfChunks];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++)
        listOfLists[i] = new List<T>();

    int currentGrp = 0;
    int currRemainder = rem;
    foreach (var el in items)
    {
        int currentElementsInGrp = listOfLists[currentGrp].Count;
        if (currentElementsInGrp == div && currRemainder > 0)
        {
            currRemainder--;
        }
        else if (currentElementsInGrp >= div)
        {
            currentGrp++;
        }
        listOfLists[currentGrp].Add(el);
    }
    return listOfLists;
}
```

then use it like this :

```
var chunks = query.GetChunks(3);
```

N.B.

in case of number of elements not divisible by the number of groups, the first groups will be bigger. e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4] --> [0,1] - [2,3] - [4]`